# How to align ag-grid-angular header dynamically

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag-grid in angular 6 and have columns and data dynamically attached to it. Now i want to align header for (both parent and children in case of multi header) dynamically. Like first column header should be left aligned and others will be center aligned.

I tried to set cellStyle and some other options i found, but none of them worked

I tried to implement it like :

```
  let headerItem = {
    headerName: name,
    children: [
      {
        headerName: name,
        field: 'col' + i + '.value',
        hide: isHidden,
        pinned: pinned,
        cellStyle: function (params) {
          try {
            return {text-align : 'center'};
          } catch (e) {
            return null;
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    cellStyle: function (params) {
          try {
            return {text-align : 'center'};
          } catch (e) {
            return null;
          }
        }
  }
```

Please guide how can i get this working...

Comment: cellStyle is only applied to cells not to headers.
What do you mean by "dynamically", do need to change it during runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the latest (if not one of the latest) versions of Ag-Grid, we have to create custom [cell header components](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#header-group-component) if we want to make any customisations to the header cells.

I have used on of the existing Ag-grid's sample, and created a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/OGCqegYVCHU2wz3T9c7r?p=preview) for you. (refer to app/custom-header.component.ts for the custom header template)

What I have done is that I have created a separate component for it, and set the template for the header as the following to align it vertically and horizontally (I am using CSS flexbox properties for that)

```
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
  {{params.displayName}}
</div>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm  .. thanks a lot. I have extended your solution to work for group header as well. Here is it : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-header-groupheader-component